# Unable to run android emulator with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

This is the error:

[image]

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 with Ubuntu 14.04 32bit. My SDK location is in `/root/Android/sdk` and the avd location is in `/root/.android`.

I have followed the instructions from this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710426/android-sdk-on-ubuntu-32bit), but nothing changed. 
I also installed kvm and checked if Virtualization Technology works in my system.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: If you are running AMD - the dialog shows you your options.

Comment: I use Intel, not AMD

Comment: So you followed this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/755779. Note that Google has stop support of 32-bit OS, so easier to upgrade Android SDK if you are on 64-bit.